# How can I change the text representing the post-edit-link in WP?

Tags: wordpress

I'm working for a Swedish client, so I need all admin stuff to display in Swedish. I've changed the `define ('WPLANG', '');` and that's all working just fine. However, under each page, the edit link still displays the English word "Edit". I'd like it to say "Redigera".

I can't seem to find the PHP that defines that. I'm running WP 3.1.4, because the client's server doesn't have PHP5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try opening your wordpress template file, ie: single.php

then from there you will see the edit_post link ie:

```
edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'twentyten' ), '<span class="edit-link">', '</span>' );
```

Just change the text to match...

if thats not something you want to do have a look [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_in_Your_Language) to add/edit your language file.